# how to find a character in a text file and save the word after that character to another file

Tags: java, arrays, file

I am trying to identify the word after the character (=) in each line of the file and save it to another file. Below is the code I have written so far but it is not working correctly as I want to. Any ideas coders?

```
My input.txt file is :

President=obama
Vice President=Biden
Head of State=Kerry
```

---

```
package Test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class Stringbuilder {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,     IOException {
    {

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"))) {
            String sCurrentLine;

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] results = sCurrentLine.split("");

                String word = sCurrentLine;

                String Sym = "=";

                for (int i = 0; i < sCurrentLine.length(); i++) {

                    if (word.contains(Sym)) {
                        // System.out.println(results[1]);

                        for (int j = 0; j < sCurrentLine.length(); j++) {

                            String content = results[j];

                            System.out.println(content);

                            File file = new File("output.txt");

                            if (!file.exists()) {
                                file.createNewFile();
                            }

                            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                            bw.write(content);
                            bw.close();

                            System.out.println("Done");

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `it is not working correctly`, care to elaborate? Provide inputs / outputs / stack traces. Voting to close for lack of details.

Comment: please add example input file and the desired output.

Comment: I have added the input file details.

Comment: Kerry is _Secretary_ of State, not Head of State, which is very different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("output.txt").getAbsoluteFile()))) {
        for (String sCurrentLine: Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("input.txt"))) {
            String[] splitted = sCurrentLine.split("=");
            if (splitted.length > 1) {
                for (int i = 1; i < splitted.length; i++) {
                    bw.write(splitted[i].split("\\s+")[0] + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree with read-lines and `split` but for the examples given just `split(,2)` and output `splitted[1]` as a line. Also there's no need to test and create the file, `new FileWriter` does that for you.

Comment: Hi David Pérez Cabrera, the names are however grouped together. How to get them on different lines? I thought + "\n" will take care of it.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 You are right, I had tried to keep this original check, but as you said, It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @sainid It prints words on different lines: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMOTVkUVAxNk1Od0E

Comment: @David Pérez Cabrera, so strange when I compile using eclipse and open the text file it don't print on different lines.

Answer (score 0):

I would add an if statement inside your nested for loop and change the initial conditions:

```
                    for (int j = 1; j < results.length(); j++) {

                        String previous=results[j-1];
                        if(previous.equals(Sym)){
                          //write results[j] to file
                      }
                    }
```